# Is there a way to force iTunes 11 to update tags?

Tags: itunes, mac

Is there any way to force iTunes 11 to rescan the music library and update the information for any tags that have been changed outside of iTunes? I know that selecting a single track and then 'Get Info" will force an update for that track, but it doesn't seem to work with multiple tracks.

Answer (score 27):

From the [MusicBrainz iTunes Guide](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/iTunes_Guide):

> ### Updating Library in iTunes
>
> #### Brute force method (full library re-scan)
>
> This method works best if
>     - you've re-tagged a whole lot of your files and don't remember which files/albums
>     - or there are far too many for the first approach
>     - or you've moved/renamed files and iTunes has lost them
>
> Ready?
>
> - Go to File > Add Folder to Library
> - Point it at the top of your iTunes directory ("My Music\iTunes\iTunes Music\Music" on Windows, by default).
> - iTunes will rescan your music, but recognize it's already imported, so you shouldn't end up with duplicate files (unless you have moved/renamed files)

You can also refresh a selection of songs by following the AppleScript based solution (on the same page linked above):

> #### Mac-only advanced method
>
> This method is a bit more complicated to set up, but easy to use.
>
> Fire up Script Editor (which is under Applications/AppleScript, but it will work with TextEdit). Paste the following code, then save as a Script called /Library/iTunes/Scripts/Refresh.scpt (create the Scripts directory if it doesn't already exist).
>
> > tell application "iTunes"
> >      refresh selection
> >     end tell
>
> Now, inside iTunes, you should see a Scripts menu (an icon of a scroll, just left of Help). The "Refresh" item on that menu will force it to re-read the tags for all tracks that you have selected.

Comment: Note that you can save that script in your users home (~/Library/iTunes/Scripts) and it works also in newest iTunes 12

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in iTunes 12.9.

Comment: Two things on the Apple Script method: 1) if you found this in the present day, you need to sub out "iTunes" with "Music"  2) I initially missed that this works on the songs you selected. So to do your whole library, go to songs, do a select-all, then run the script

Comment: I successfully used the advanced method with the new Music application on Mac OS Big Sur v11.1. I changed "iTunes" to "Music" in the script and copied the script to /Library/Music/Scripts/Refresh.scpt and it worked perfectly. Very tidy solution which I have been searching for quite a while.

Answer (score 6):

You can go to iTunes->Preferences->Advanced, uncheck `Keep iTunes Media folder organized`, OK, then go back and check the option again. It will rescan all track after you click OK.

Comment: I just tried this with iTunes 11.0.2 and it did not update the tags.

Comment: This now works fine in Music 1.1.6.37 on Big Sur 11.6.

Comment: Thank you, this was useful to me on iTunes for Windows!

Answer (score 1):

Building on M K's answer, the following script won't stop the first time it hits a file which can't be found:

```
tell application "Music"
  repeat with aTrack in selection
    try
        refresh aTrack
    end try
  end repeat
end tell
```

**Edit**: in MacOS older than Catalina, change `"Music"` to `"iTunes"` for this to work.

Comment: Interesting, though it's probably useful to figure out what your problem songs are...I modified my Apple Script to output the song information to a file as it goes

Comment: My use case was that I wanted to remove the annoying and redundant suffix "(original mix)" from thousands of my MP3s. Building a smart playlist to find them was easy, but I had to write a program to retag them - https://github.com/ben-xo/unoriginator - then this script was needed to refresh all the tracks in this view.